# EXIF images - Flip Image on Server, or Client-side?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, server, imagemagick

I'm having issues handling EXIF tagged photos on the web, which were uploaded from my cellphone.

I see there being a couple potential options:

1. Rotating the image on server using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).
2. Rotating image and altering EXIF on Android, THEN uploading to server.

Anyone have experience in what a "proper" or recommended method would be if I wanted to do this?

Or perhaps, it's not common for shops to handle their own image data? Ie. Use [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) or the like.

Thanks!

Comment: If there is an orientation EXIF field in the meta data of the image, Imagemagick can automatically correct it using `convert -auto-orient image.suffix new_image.suffix`

Comment: `having issues handling EXIF tagged photos on the web,`. Well than that has nothing to do with Android. Solve it on the webserver. Handling exif tagged image files is nothing special. Update your server software.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks, and this would be suggested on the Android device, and then upload to the server with such orientation?

Comment: @greenapps Thanks, I'm using Firebase Cloud Storage. I'd have to trigger a cloud function to rotate it, which I'm wondering would be inefficient... That's what you're essentially saying to do correct? Just not sure what "the best" way would be.

Comment: `@njho` You can do it on a server with Imagemagick